# run SQL Server 2005 Job from intranet page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to run a SQL Server 2005 job from an asp.net intranet page?  I've been opening up SQL Server 2005 and manually running this and thought it would really be convenient if I could just click a button on a web page instead.

Comment: It would be even more convenient if you could schedule it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: yes it would, but we don't run it on a predictable schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question not too long ago and got some good results. The short answer is "Schedule an agent job when you click the button". See Remus Rusanu's answer on this question:

[Run long-running sproc (that doesn’t need to return) from ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595772/run-long-running-sproc-that-doesnt-need-to-return-from-asp-net-page)

Comment: Looks an interesting technique but I'm not sure what benefit it would have over and above simply scheduling the job directly by executing the relevant msdb procedure? Is there some way of getting around the security issue with this approach (e.g. with certificates)?

Comment: Well you said you want to run a "job" so I think we are all assuming this is a long-running query which you won't be able to do by clicking a button because it will timeout.

Comment: I'm not the OP! I assumed he meant run a SQL Agent job hence the confusion, I can see it could be read two ways now though.